# Iterate over items in one array and groups of items in second array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops, shell

I have two arrays containing file names

```
files_ref=( $(find . -name '*.fasta') )
files_fq=( $(find . -name '*.fastq') )
```

I understand that if I want to iterate over pairs of items I would do something like this:

```
for i in "${!files_ref[@]}"; do
    printf "%s is in %s\n" "${files_ref[i]}" "${files_fq[i]}"
done
```

However, my second arrays looks like this

```
file_ref=(
  DI1.fasta
  DI2.fasta
  WT1.fasta

)
files_fq=(
  DI1_P1.fastq
  DI1_P2.fastq
  DI1_P3.fastq
  DI2_P1.fastq
  DI2_P2.fastq
  DI2_P3.fastq
  WT1_P1.fastq
  WT1_P2.fastq
  WT1_P3.fastq
)
```

I would have to iterate over files_ref with all its correspoding items in the same group:

```
DI1.fasta with DI1_P1.fastq DI1_P2.fastq DI1_P3.fastq
DI2.fasta with DI2_P1.fastq DI2_P2.fastq DI2_P3.fastq
WT1.fasta with WT1_P1.fastq WT1_P2.fastq WT1_P3.fastq
```

Any suggestions?

...to be more clear

I would need iterations like this:

```
DI1.fasta DI1_P1.fastq
DI1.fasta DI1_P2.fastq
DI1.fasta DI1_P3.fastq
DI2.fasta DI2_P1.fastq
DI2.fasta DI2_P2.fastq
DI2.fasta DI2_P3.fastq
WT1.fasta WT1_P1.fastq
WT1.fasta WT1_P2.fastq
WT1.fasta WT1_P3.fastq
```

Comment: What's the language? Please add the language tag.

Comment: I added it, it is unix

Comment: Are your files in the same directory?

Comment: yes, they are in the same directory

Comment: oh in addition, for each combination I need to run a command on it and output to file so for example echo DI1.fasta DI1_P1.fastq > DI1_P1.out

Comment: Which language is this? Unix is not a language. You tagged the question _shell_, which means POSIX shell or unix sh, but both shells don't have arrays, so your question does not make sense.

Comment: I am running this on a server which uses bash shell, when I run there I can create an array correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could go about it is by extracting the prefixes first (DI1, DI2, WT1) and then doing a double iteration. For example this Bash script would produce the output you want:

```
prefixes=()
for name in "${file_ref[@]}"; do
    prefixes+=("${name%.*}")
done

for prefix in "${prefixes[@]}"; do

    echo -n "$prefix.fasta with "

    for fq in "${files_fq[@]}"; do
        if [[ $fq == $prefix* ]]; then
            echo -n "$fq "
        fi
    done
    echo # add a newline
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working very well, amazing, yeah it is a nested loop followed by an if statement to check if the file has same prefix, got it. I am not sure why this question had been closed but it is different from what they said it is a duplicate because this is not about subsequent pairs of files, it is one file in the first array paired with not one file in second array but one group of files, if you can vote to  reopen appreciated